# Set default value of dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

This code will create an array of 100 elements and set the value of each to false.

```
bool boolArray[100] = false;
```

How can I set the default value of a dynamic array?

```
void Foo(int size)
{
    bool boolArray = new bool[size];
    //Now what?
}
```

Comment: It's `bool *boolArray`, not `bool boolArray` (that would be just a single bool, so the assignment of `new something` wouldn't even make sense).

Comment: The first line should be `... = {false};`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In standard C++ you can default-initialize just about anything, including that array:

```
bool* boolArray = new bool[size]();     // Zero-initialized
```

Complete program that also checks the result, and deallocates the array:

```
bool foo( int size )
{
    bool* boolArray = new bool[size]();     // Zero-initialized

    // Check that it is indeed zero-initialized:   
    for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
        if( boolArray[i] ) { delete[] boolArray; return false; }
    }
    delete[] boolArray; return true;
}

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << (foo( 42 )? "OK" : "Ungood compiler") << endl;
}
```

Whether your compiler will accept or even do the Right Thing is another matter.

So, in practice, *if* you feel an irresistible urge to use a raw array, then perhaps better use `std::fill` or some such, or even a raw loop.

But note the repeated `delete[]`-expressions. Such redundant code is very easy to get wrong: it's Evil™. And there's much else that can go wrong with use of raw arrays, so as a novice, just Say No™ to raw arrays and raw pointers and such.

Instead, use standard library containers, which manage allocation, initialization, copying and deallocation for you – correctly. There is a little problem with that, though, namely a premature optimization in `std::vector<bool>`, which otherwise would be the natural choice. Essentially `std::vector<bool>` uses just one bit per value, so that it can't hand out references to `bool` elements, but instead hands out proxy objects…

So, for `bool` elements, use e.g. a `std::bitset` (when the size is known at compile time), or e.g. a `std::deque`, as follows:

```
#include <deque>

bool foo( int size )
{
    std::deque<bool> boolArray( size );     // Zero-initialized

    for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
        if( boolArray[i] ) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << (foo( 42 )? "OK" : "Ungood compiler") << endl;
}
```

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 12):

Use [`std::fill` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill) or [`std::fill_n` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill_n/).

```
std::fill_n(boolArray, length, defaultValue);
std::fill(boolArray, boolArray + length, defaultValue);
```

*Side note: try using `std::vector` instead.*

Comment: Using `std::vector` for this has some problems; see my answer. Also, while using `std::fill` is certainly a good solution to a generalization of the OP's problem, it's not necessary for the particular problem at hand. Again, see my answer. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2):

```
bool* boolArray = new bool[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    boolArray[i] = false;
}
```

Comment: +1: not as "elegant" as Mehrdad's std::fill suggestion (also +1-ed), but so fundamental and re-purposeable it's a great, productive approach to reach for when unsure.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
void Foo(int size)
{
    // bool boolArray = new bool[size];
    // Did you mean bool*?
    // Try and avoid direct allocation of memory.
    // Memory allocation should be done inside an object that 
    // actively manages it.

    // Normally I would recommend a vector
    std::vector<bool>   boolArray(size, false);

    // But. And a Big but. Is that the standards committee decided to
    // specialize the vector for bool so that each element only takes
    // a single bit. Unfortunately this had some side effects that were
    // made its use not perfect (time/assign-ability).

    // So we can try a boost array
    boost::array<bool, size>   boolArray;
}
```

Comment: Uhm, just a nit, you can't use run-time `size` as template argument (as in the code as it is as I'm writing this). Perhaps boost has array that allows run-time size? I landed on `std::queue` in my answer, but everyone has different preferences... Cheers,

Comment: uh, typo, i meant i landed on `std::deque` in my answer, as can be seen in the answer... but anyway, your code as it is right now, with `boost::array<bool, size>`, where `size` is a run time value, won't compile. Cheers & hth.,