# Default value of dynamic bool array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, boolean

I need to create a bool array with an unknown length passed by parameter. So, I have the following code:

```
void foo (int size) {

    bool *boolArray = new bool[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            if (!boolArray[i]) {

                cout << boolArray[i];

            }
    }
}
```

I thought that a boolean array was initializing with false values...

Then, if I run that code in Eclipse (on Ubuntu), it works fine for me, the function prints all the values because **!boolArray[i]** return true (but the values are not false values, they are garbage values). If I run it in Visual Studio, the values are garbage values too, but the function does not print any value (because **!boolArray[i]** returns false). Why the array values are not false values by default?!? And why **!boolArray[i]** returns false in Visual Studio but it returns true in Eclipse?!?

I read this question: [Set default value of dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262914/set-default-value-of-dynamic-array), so if I change the code like the following, it works fine for me too (in Eclipse and in Visual Studio)! But I have no idea why.

```
void foo (int size) {

    bool *boolArray = new bool[size]();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            if (!boolArray[i]) {

                cout << boolArray[i];

            }      
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad English!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour In fact, I have two questions... That post answers one question but does not why !boolArray[i] returns false in Visual Studio but it returns true in Eclipse...

Comment: It is undefined behavior to use an uninitialized variable, so it does not really say that but I don't think that aspect makes it not a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `()` for a POD instantiation, invokes *value initialization* in C++03 and later. In C++98 it invoked *default initialization*. But both reduce to *zero initialization* for POD types, and for booleans zero is false.

E.g., if `S` is a POD `struct`, and you have a variable

```
S o;
```

then you can zero it by doing

```
o = S();
```

No need for unsafe and ugly `memset`.

---

By the way, `std::vector<bool>` is a higher level alternative to your raw array of `bool`, but due to what's now seen as premature optimization it has a bit odd behavior: it supports an implementation with each boolean value represented by a single bit, and so dereferencing an iterator doesn't give you a reference to a `bool` as one might expect from general `std::vector`. So a better alternative is e.g. `std::vector<My_bool_enum>`, with `My_bool_enum` properly defined. Or just `std::vector<char>`. ;-)

---

Regarding

> “And why `!boolArray[i]` returns `false` in Visual Studio but it returns `true` in Eclipse?!?”

It's just that Visual C++ chooses efficiency, not initializing where it doesn't have to, while the compiler used in Eclipse (presumably g++) does initialize even though it doesn't have to and isn't requested to do.

I prefer the Visual C++ behavior here for two reasons:

- A main idea in C++ is that **you don't pay for what you don't use**, and the Visual C++ behavior here is in line with that idea.
- Zero-initialization can easily give users the false impression that their code works, when in fact it's not portable.